# Every linux-based system freezes after hibernation

Tags: suspend, hibernate

I've a rather unusual situation here; I've tried kali, ubuntu and fedora, and the same issue occurs every time; when I close the lid of my laptop it goes into hibernation. Then when I turn it back on, my mouse and keyboard are unresponsive for about 10 seconds, then I'm able to control my mouse, but I can never type my password to access the system. And like I said, it's happening across all Linux-based OS's, which is very strange. I've tried reinstalling the OS - the issue persisted. I have a sony vaio fit 15. Does anyone know what might be causing this? I have an intel integrated GPU.

Comment: "which is very strange" Why is that strange? Answer seems easy: your problem is hardware related. Your hardware does not provide the OS with  the correct information. Solution is simple too: don't use hibernation but shutdown the system. Get an ssd if you do not have one and shutdown your system. Rebooting with an ssd should take less than 10 seconds. And it might be worth while gathering logs and such to submit a report so others might create a fix for this :)

Comment: @Rinzwind I tried suspend as well, same result tbh. However, when I lock the machine manually from the main screen, I can type out my password no problem, so this problem occurs only if the screen goes off.
Edit: I'll gather up logs, that's a good idea.